# How to set a context for an asynchronous WinHttpWebSocketSend call?

Tags: asynchronous, websocket, callback, winhttp

WinHttpSendRequest has a dwContext parameter so that I can read the context from WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK function. This context makes it possible to tell which WinHttpSendRequest is for the current callback.

Unfortunately and weirdly, though, WinHttpWebSocketSend does NOT have such context parameter at all. As a result, it is not possible to distinguish between multiple WinHttpWebSocketSend calls within WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK function.

Can anybody help me with this please?

For your reference, I am trying to modify the following example to work with a websocket.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383138%28VS.85%29.aspx#additional

The websocket resource I am trying to get is: https://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1.
Once connected, you can send the following resource string for testing:

> [{"ticket":"test"},{"format":"SIMPLE"},{"type":"trade","codes":["KRW-BTC","BTC-BCH"]},{"format":"SIMPLE"}]

If things go well, you will receive:

> {"mk":"KRW-BTC","tms":1523531768829,"td":"2018-04-12","ttm":"11:16:03","ttms":1523531763000,"tp":7691000.0,"tv":0.00996719,"ab":"BID","pcp":7429000.00000000,"c":"RISE","cp":262000.00000000,"sid":1523531768829000,"st":"SNAPSHOT"}
>    {"mk":"BTC-BCH","tms":1523531745481,"td":"2018-04-12","ttm":"11:15:48","ttms":1523531748370,"tp":0.09601999,"tv":0.18711789,"ab":"BID","pcp":0.09618000,"c":"FALL","cp":0.00016001,"sid":15235317454810000,"st":"SNAPSHOT"}
>    {"mk":"KRW-BTC","tms":1523531769250,"td":"2018-04-12","ttm":"11:16:04","ttms":1523531764000,"tp":7691000.0,"tv":0.07580113,"ab":"BID","pcp":7429000.00000000,"c":"RISE","cp":262000.00000000,"sid":1523531769250000,"st":"REALTIME"}

I have a source project file you can download:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiVorOunaPYdhAuHrggDk2EYa2X7

Once you download, compile and run it. Then you will see a dialog with 'Download' button and it will show
- http://www.microsoft.com
- WebSocket check box disabled

Click the Download button will show asynchronous WinHttpSendRequest working with a general site like http://www.microsoft.com.

I wanted to modify this demo program for a websocket server (https://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1).  For that purpose, I '#define'd WSS_API_UPBIT
Next, uncomment AsynchDemo.cpp's line 19 to

## define WSS_API_UPBIT

Then run the demo again.  This time you will see a little different dialog with
- https://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1
- WebSocket check box enabled

Now, check the Websocket box and press Download.
It will crash becasue of no context within callbacks.

thx

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpwebsocketcompleteupgrade is for - you pass in the new context that's specifically for the web socket [make sure you set the winhttp option on the handle before sending it - there's an example here in synchronous mode that might help: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/WinhttpWebsocket/cpp/WinhttpWebsocket.cpp).  I also think you need to set the callback function option on the handle returned from CompleteUpgrade() to get notified after reads and writes complete.